# Method cannot be applied to java.lang.Object (should accept object of specific class as argument)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a string from the content of an object with a custom method in my Android application. The object is an instance of the class `Game` and is contained in an `arraylist`:

```
public class Game {

    private static List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
    private String teamName1;
    private String teamName2;
    private int goalsP1;
    private int goalsP2;

    private String result;


    public Game(String teamName1, String teamName2, int goalsP1, int goalsP2)
    {
        this.teamName1 = teamName1;
        this.teamName2 = teamName2;
        this.goalsP1 = goalsP1;
        this.goalsP2 = goalsP2;
    }

    public static List getGames() {
    return games;
    }

    public static void addGameToArray(Game randGame) { games.add(randGame);}

    public static String getStringFromGame(Game randGame) {
        randGame.result = randGame.result + randGame.teamName1 + randGame.goalsP1 + randGame.goalsP2 + randGame.teamName2;
        return randGame.result;
    }
```

In my `MainActivity` I'm trying to call the `getStringFromGame`:

```
    Game game1 = new Game("Man City ","Real Madrid", 5 ,0);

    Game.addGameToArray(game1);

    String result = Game.getStringFromGame(Game.getGames().get(0));
```

I get an error:

> getStringFromGame cannot be applied to java.lang.Object

What is going wrong?

Comment: Where is `getGames` defined?

Comment: Seems like the `getGames` method is missing or returning a wrong type. Make sure you parameter of the method is of type Game. That is why it returns an error. Because You are trying to set a different type in. Like here in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410758/java-lang-string-cannot-be-applied-to-java-lang-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is statically typed. This error message translates to "You have passed an `Object` to `getStringFromGame`, which we know takes a `Game`.

You don't show your `getGames` definition, but the error message indicates you're returning an `Object` value from it. Because `Game` extends `Object` (and not the other way around), you have a problem. A function that is expecting a `Game` will reject being passed an `Object`.

Given the `get(0)` here:

```
String result = Game.getStringFromGame(Game.getGames().get(0));
```

The `return type` of `getGames()` is probably a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of some sort. If the `type` of a collection is not specified, Java assumes everything in that collection is of type `Object`. [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) can be used to define what it is a collection of. So rather than a signature like this:

```
 public List getGames() { ... }
```

You want something like this:

```
 public List<Game> getGames() { ... }
```

(Note that `List` is a subtype of `Collection`. If you care about order, then use `List`, otherwise you should replace it with `Collection`).

Further, it seems to indicate that you are randomizing the order of that list. In which case an even better solution would be:

```
 public Game getRandomGame() { ... }
```

Which avoids the issue of generics altogether and keeps the randomization encapsulated.

**Post-Update Addendum**

As a minor aside, this might get you into trouble:

```
public class Game {

    private static List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
    ...
    public static List getGames() {
        return games;
    }
    ...
}
```

Because you're declaring `games` as a `static` member field, any instantiated game may update that. This can get confusing and hard to predict very fast. It might be better to put these in a separate class (`GameLibrary`?) like so:

```
public class GameLibrary {
     private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();

     public List getGames() {
         return games;
     }
}
```

This way, code using one instance of `GameLibrary` has no access to every other instance of `GameLibrary`. As it stands, *any* instantiation of `Game` can modify your the `private static List<Game> games` value... which breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and great explanation! My code works fine now. I added the getGames method in the code of my question.

Comment: @Aelian Glad to help! Definitely check out my addendum: may help guard against future problems.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're returning a generic list with `getGames()`.

So define it as

```
public static List<Game> getGames() { return games; }
```

and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getGames()` method obviously returns a `List<Something?!>` instead of a `List<Game>`. You can't pass an argument that is not a `Game` or it's subclass to the `getGames()` method since it expects a `Game` to be passed.

Just make the method return a `List<Game>` and it'll work.